# Download file via inbuilt download Service

Tags: android, download

I am trying to download a file from remote server in my app. I do not want to right custom code for this. I want to download the file via inbuilt downloader(which android has built in). How to do that? And is it the correct option for this:

```
dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Request request = new Request(
                       Uri.parse("http://www.vogella.de/img/lars/LarsVogelArticle7.png"));
enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code it's really working...

```
DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

            Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse("http://www.vogella.de/img/lars/LarsVogelArticle7.png");
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);

            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                    DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                            | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("Demo")
                    .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/test_folder", "testimage");

            mgr.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Permissions are not required??

Comment: I tried but its showing msg that minimum 15 reputation for vote up